how to make Jackson SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filterOutAllExcept work for nested objects
how can I keep all the nested objects with the same property names?
for example. Top level class is Policy.
@JsonFilter("myFilter")
public class Policy {
    String name;
    String number;
    List<Participant> participants;
    List<Asset> assets;
    Map<String, String> additionalFields;
}

@JsonFilter("myFilter")
public class Participant {
    String name;
    String number;
    List<Asset> assets;
    Map<String, String> additionalFields;
}

@JsonFilter("myFilter")
public class Asset {
    String name;
    String number;
    Map<String, String> additionalFields;
}

now, I want to exclude all fields except additionalFields on all the objects in response. I have the below implementation, but this removes everything and only keep additionalFields on Policy.
SimpleFilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider() .addFilter("myFilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("additionalFields"));


the case in your description, if not include other dependenciey, it actually is 2 filter to achieve(because the filter that your use behavior is top to bottom, and judge with the property name) you goal. for example
@JsonFilter("policyFilter")
public class Policy {
    String name;
    String number;
    List<Participant> participants;
    List<Asset> assets;
    Map<String, String> additionalFields;
}

@JsonFilter("myFilter")
public class Participant {
    String name;
    String number;
    List<Asset> assets;
    Map<String, String> additionalFields;
}

@JsonFilter("myFilter")
public class Asset {
    String name;
    String number;
    Map<String, String> additionalFields;
}


PropertyFilter policyFilter=  SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("additionalFields","participants","assets");
PropertyFilter myFilter =  SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("additionalFields");
SimpleFilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider() .addFilter("myFilter", myFilter );



if you want to use one filter to controll serialization, the jackson standard filter not suppoer such nest property, there exists some discuss in https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1040.
but there exists some Community solution. you could use them
https://github.com/krishna81m/jackson-nested-prop-filter
if you use the solution above, the code should be
@JsonFilter("myFilter")
public class Policy {
    String name;
    String number;
    List<Participant> participants;
    List<Asset> assets;
    Map<String, String> additionalFields;
}

// @JsonFilter("myFilter")
public class Participant {
    String name;
    String number;
    List<Asset> assets;
    Map<String, String> additionalFields;
}

// @JsonFilter("myFilter") there is no need to specific such config,access graph already in NestedPropertyFilterProvider
public class Asset {
    String name;
    String number;
    Map<String, String> additionalFields;
}

        FilterProvider filterProvider =  new NestedPropertyFilterProvider()
                .addFilter("myFilter",
                        NestedBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(Policy.class,
                                "additionalFields",
                                "participants.additionalFields", // nest property
                                "assets.additionalFields")); // nest property

